# The specified cast from a materialized 'System.Int16' type to the 'System.Int32' type is not valid

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I use 'entity framework 6' to load data from a database. Currently i want to load data from a view and not from a table with ef6. I have created a class with only properties (a plain old c# object (poco)).

You can see a poco class here:

```
public class Person {

   public string Name { get; set; }
   public int? PhoneNumber { get; set }
   public int? Age { get; set; }

}
```

Then i want to load the view with this code:

```
var sql = "SELECT Name, PhoneNumber, Age from Person;"

using(var context = new PersonContext()){

      var personList = context.Database.SqlQuery<Person>(sql).toList();   
}
```

On runtime the program throw the following error:

```
The specified cast from a materialized 'System.Int16' type to the 'System.Int32' type is not valid.
```

So I know the **property type** and the **database column type** are not equal. But how can i find which property in the code is not equal with database column? Since in the real application i have a lot of properties, this question is important for me to find the property.

Comment: You can programetically do it using [GetType()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.gettype?view=netframework-4.8) But it would be good while you would define database in that time create data property as per your class property or vice versa.

Comment: Do you have an example for me?

Comment: Example is little big cannot set on comment.

Comment: Also you can try `YourPocoProperty.GetType().Equals(TypeOfDataBaseProperty.GetType())`

Comment: I don't know the database type in the program code. So i can't go over all properties to check which is not correct.